# How can I copy a file in Perl and maintain its timestamp?

Tags: perl, file, copy, timestamp

I am using the File::Copy module to copy a file in Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use File::Copy;

copy("somefile.log", "copiedfile.log");
```

I would like to preserve timestamps (particularly the modification time), but this doesn't appear to be an option.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this without resorting to making a system call to "cp -p"?

Comment: save the timestamp (use stat), do the copy and apply the timestamp again (using utime) won't work? (same as the 'touch' command)

Comment: James, you comment in brian's answer: "I would find it surprising if the vast Perl libraries don't have a "copy and preserve attributes" function (that works on Linux)", what do you mean by "works on Linux"? If you are talking about cp -p, the source code of Linux does exactly what I suggested above, use stat and utime to do the "preserve". Here it is:
      (*(x->xstat)) (src_path, &src_sb)
...

   utb.actime = src_sb.st_atime;
   utb.modtime = src_sb.st_mtime;

   utime (dst_path, &utb)

Comment: Murali, Perl has a clean "copy and preserve attributes" command, rmscopy (see ghostdog74's answer below), but it's only available on VMS systems.  On Windows, I believe syscopy would do the job, since I think the standard semantics for copying a file on Windows preserves timestamps.  On Linux this is not the case, so a three line "copy, stat, utime" combination seems to be the cleanest "pure Perl" solution.  This seems inelegant to me, but appears to be the only option without making a backticked system call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) to get the timestamp and [utime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/utime.html) to set it. If you can get away with it, `system` isn't always bad. You're never going to make something faster than `cp -p`. You'd think that [File::Copy](http://www.metacpan.org/module/File::Copy) would do it, but on unix it doesn't. Abigail filed a [RT #96158](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=96158), but it was closed with no action. He has a presentation about its brokenness, but I haven't seen it online.

Comment: stat and utime are an option, but don't really meed the "straightforward" criteria.  Perhaps I am expecting too much, although I would find it surprising if the vast Perl libraries don't have a "copy and preserve attributes" function (that works on Linux).

Comment: Maybe your definition of straightforward is different. As for being surprised about the lack of a good module, it's because no one cares to believe how broken File::Copy is, so no one comes up with a better one.

Comment: It looks like this is the best solution.  In my program I've gone for `cp -p`, which is acceptable and simple for a fairly throwaway script that I don't intend to distribute, but I think the clean solution would be to wrap up the copy, stat and utime into a neat library function.

Answer (score 4):

Check [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html). Look under `syscopy` or `rmscopy`. It talks about timestamps there.

Comment: rmscopy seemed promising, but is only available on VMS systems (not Linux, which I am using).  The formatting of the documentation makes this a bit unclear, but I have checked in the Copy.pm file in my 5.10.0 installation, and rmscopy isn't defined.

Comment: To paraphrase the perl docs: *`syscopy` preserves OS attributes. Except on Unix, where it doesn't.*

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
# emulate unix "cp -p"
# to submit as an answer to
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657296/how-can-i-copy-a-file-in-perl-and-maintain-its-timestamp
use strict; use warnings;
use Time::Local; use POSIX qw(strftime);
use File::Copy "cp"; # keep permissions identical

my $source='aaa';
my $target='junk';
unlink $target if -e $target;
my $source_mtime=(stat $source)[9];
cp $source, $target; 
# now all 4 times of $target are equal to the time when this command was executed, at least in bash
showfiledate($source);
showfiledate($target);
utime($source_mtime,$source_mtime,$target); 
# now atime, mtime, and birthtime are identical to $source mtime, at least in bash
showfiledate($target);

sub showfiledate
{
    my $file=shift;
    my $mtime=(stat $file)[9];
    my $dateJ=strftime '%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S', localtime($mtime);
    print $dateJ, ' ', $file,"\n";
}
```